# Is it possible to work without tmux on current Debian?

Tags: linux, tmux

One website recommends installing *tmux* so that the process continues after the user disconnects. I wonder if this can be done without extra dependency.

Comment: You can expect Debian 10 or newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) is [required by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html), it should be available out of the box. Its main purpose is to make the process survive when the user disconnects.

To learn more see [*Difference between `nohup`, `disown` and `&`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/108618).

Still `tmux` (or `screen`) is much more useful. It's a terminal multiplexer; immunity to disconnects is just one of its features.